# How to persist logged in user in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, next.js

How can I possibly persist user data even after refresh? I was thinking about storing it inside local storage but that mean flash of unauthenticated content or storing it in cookie, but this would be very problematic when working with redux. I'm looking for a solution that will work with redux and will not cause unauthorized page content to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jwt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) in your Next.js project.

Please refer to [this](https://medium.com/swlh/jwt-json-web-tokens-user-authentication-in-next-js-web-application-51deab8f2e96)

And there is a way to integrate [Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/ultimate-guide-nextjs-authentication-auth0/) as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an npm package called [Next Iron Session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-iron-session). It works really well with nextjs api and getServersideProps. It's based on [iron](https://github.com/hapijs/iron) by [Hapijs](https://hapi.dev/)

Comment: Update: Now iron is all in one bundle as `iron-session`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iron-session